# Different rules for the same view-id PrettyFaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, prettyfaces

I have a jsf page which receive between 2 and 6 parameters, I would like to make this url look better, so I started to use pretty faces. When I create the rule for 2 parameters, everything works perfectly, but when I create the second rule, the pages also works, the url is correctly like I wish but I receive error messages in the Eclipse Console.
I think it's because I'm trying to create a rule for the same view-id... is that possible?

pretty-config:

```
  <url-mapping id="departamento">
   <pattern value="/#{codDep}/#{departamento} " />
   <view-id value="/departamento.jsf" />
  </url-mapping>

 <url-mapping parentId="departamento" id="sessao">
  <pattern value="/#{codSec}/#{secao}" />
  <view-id value="/departamento.jsf" />
 </url-mapping>
```

Console Error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "javax.faces.resource"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at project.Controller.inicializar(Controller.java:82)
```

Controller method:

```
 public void inicializar(ComponentSystemEvent event)
{
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
if (!context.isPostback())
{

    departamento = new Departamento(Integer.parseInt(codigoDepartamento), descricaoDepartamento, null, null);
    }
  }
```

The problem is that It shouldn't pass this parameter "javax.faces.resource"
and sometimes "css", which I don't even know where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this happens because a JSF resource request (which contains `javax.faces.resource`), matches one of your patterns. PrettyFaces intercepts the request and parts of the requested path are written to your beans.

You will have to change your pattern so that it only matches the URL you want to and not stuff like JSF resources, CSS or image files. You could either add some unique fixed string prefix like `/dep/` like this:

```
<url-mapping id="departamento">
  <pattern value="/dep/#{codDep}/#{departamento} " />
  <view-id value="/departamento.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

Or restrict the values allowed for the path parameters. If `codDep` for example is a number, you could use this:

```
<url-mapping id="departamento">
  <pattern value="/#{ /[0-9]+/ codDep }/#{departamento} " />
  <view-id value="/departamento.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

See this part of the PrettyFaces documentation for details:

http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/Configuration.html#config.pathparams.regex

Comment: Thanks @chkal, I did your first suggest before your answer and it works,  I'll try the second now.
Just another question, could I retrieve the first param (#{codDep} but hide it using prettyfaces? Because it's a number and I didn't like to my url be like: www.url.com/1/departamento
Also, because in my second rule would be:  www.url.com/1/departamento/2/item, for example.

But I can't remove the param because I use preRenderView in a class which I need this param to search on the database.

Any Suggest?
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need the ID to load the entry for the database, then you will also have to include it in the URL. That's the idea of PrettyFaces. Bookmarkable URLs that include anything the application needs to know to render the page. If you don't want to include the id and the department names are unique, you could think about changing your database query to use the name instead of the id to load it.